# matlab bar colormap returns the same color for all bars

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a problem with using `bar` and colormap.

I have a csv file like this which contains completion time for six tasks:

```
34,22,103,22,171,26
24,20,41,28,78,28
37,19,60,23,141,24
...
```

and I create a bar chart with of the means, and add the std variation errorbar.

```
res = csvread('sorting_results.csv');
figure();
y = mean(res)';
e = std(res);
hold on;
bar(y);
errorbar(y,e,'.r');
title('Sorting completion time');
ylabel('Completion time (seconds)');
xlabel('Task No.');
hold off;
colormap(summer(size(y,2)));
```

Why is the output like this? Why do the bars have the same color? And how do I put legends to the six bars?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece of code that does the magic. It doesn't use the canonical technique mentioned by @am304, as you will have a hard time setting up the legend with it. Here, for each one of the 6 input values, we plot a full 6 bars: one bar with the value and the remaining five set to zero.

```
x = rand(1,6);     %create data
x_diag = diag(x);  %zero matrix with diagonal filled with x
cmap = summer(6);  %define colors to use (summer colomap)

figure('color','w','Render','Zbuffer'); %create figure

%bar plot for each x value
for ind_data = 1:length(x)
    h_bar = bar( x_diag(ind_data, :)); %bar plot
    set( get(h_bar,'children'), 'FaceVertexCData', cmap(ind_data,:) ) ; %color
    hold on;
end
colormap('summer');

%legend-type info
hleg = legend( ('a':'f')' ); 
set(hleg, 'box', 'off');
%xticks info
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', ('a':'f')' );

%plot errors
e = ones(1,6) * 0.05;
errorbar(x, e,'.r');
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14, 'YLim', [ 0 (max(x) + max(e) + 0.1) ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Coloring 2-D Bars According to Height](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/bar-and-area-graphs.html#f10-23913) in the MATLAB documentation. Only the first colour of the colormap is used to colour the faces, you need a bit of hack (as per code on that doc page) to do what you want.